# Merging Tables Using MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've created a database with two tables: `Table1` and `Table2`.

`Table1` Contains the following data:

```
Account#    Account Owner
1           Person1
2           Person2
```

`Table2` Contains:

```
Account#      Date Modified     Status
1             5/15/2011         Open
2             4/15/2011         Closed
1             5/21/2011         Pending
2             6/15/2011         Cancelled
```

Using SQL, how can I merge these two tables so that It will give me the latest status for each account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it:

```
SELECT Table1.[Account#],
       Table1.[Account Owner],
       L.LastOfDate,
       Table2.Status
FROM   ((SELECT Table2.[Account#],
                Max(Table2.[Date Modified]) AS LastOfDate
        FROM   Table2
        GROUP  BY Table2.[Account#]) AS L
        INNER JOIN Table1
          ON L.[Account#]=Table1.[Account#])
       INNER JOIN Table2
         ON (L.[Account#]=Table2.[Account#])
            AND (L.LastOfDate=Table2.[Date Modified]);
```

Will result in:

```
Account#    Account Owner    LastOfDate     Status
1           Person1          05/21/2011     Pending
2           Person2          06/15/2011     Cancelled
```

Comment: There's a bit of a problem, if the dates on Table 2 are not in order, the query will return the last row instead of the on with the latest date.

Comment: @HenryTaylor I initially mistakenly used `Last()` instead of `Max()`. I corrected it straight away but I don't know if you saw the corrected version or not. The dates do not need to be in any sorted order, but you need to make sure you have indexes on all the columns used for the joins, including the `Modified Date`.